# Luks Disk Encryption

Tags: automount, luks

I have setup disk encryption with 'LUKS' and configure it to auto mount when the system boots up. So now as it supposed, it prompts me a passphrase when the system boots up. If i enter the correct passphrase it continuous the system.

So in some cases i want to escape from typing passphrase. Is there a way to do that.?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your LUKS partition to NOT auto mount.

1) Delete (comment out) /etc/crypttab

```
sudo nano /etc/crypttab
```

Add a "#" in the front of your LUKS partition.

2) Edit /etc/fstab and use the "noauto" option for your LUKS volume

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Change the "auto"  in the 4th column to read "noauto"

3) You will then need to mount your LUKS partition manually.

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/your_LUKS_Partition your_luks_name

mount /dev/mapper/your_LUKS_name
```

You will have to use sudo with that second command if you do not have the users option in fstab (in addition to noauto)

By removing /etc/crypttab, the luks process is not run at boot-time, and adding "noauto" makes sure that the encrypted volume is not attempted to be mounted.

You need to change the names in the above commands to the names of your partitions /LUKS. You can see the names in your config files.

Comment: I dont want to disable auto mount or comment out `/etc/crypttab` process. What i want is escape the passphrase prompt when i needed. So that other times i can enter my passphrase to mount it.

Comment: As it is now, you do not have that option. Your choices are to disable automount as I outlined, write your own init script , see http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/initramfs/ or modify the Ubuntu script, or file a bug report (feature request).

Answer (score 0):

I was seeking for how to auto mount a LUKS USB drive and I found my answer here

https://www.howtoforge.com/automatically-unlock-luks-encrypted-drives-with-a-keyfile

Or if you want automount when you login try with libpam-mount
sudo apt-get install libpam-mount
edit : etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml.
by adding after  :

I hope that will help you